# Smart Filter on Smart Object only on Selection Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, smartobject, filter

If my layer is rasterized and I select something (say with the marquees ellipse), the filters apply only to that selection - moreover - they apply *centered* on the selection.

For example, using the Spherize filter on rasterized layer with a portion selected with the marquees ellipse, then the center of the sphere would be the center of the ellipse made with the marquees.

If my layer is a smart object, it doesn't work this way. All filters are centered on the entire layer.

For the sake of avoiding the xy problem, here's what I'm trying to do:
A have a text layer wherein I want the text to look like it's going to burst open like a balloon. So I want to select some of the text to spherize so it looks like it's bursting or blowing up.

Answer (score 1):

---

The Smart Filters thumbnail in the Layers Panel is a **mask**. Treat it like any other mask and it will hide/reveal areas of the filter.

[image]

- Add the smart Filter,
- Fill the Smart Filter thumbnail with black
- Make your selection
- Fill that area on the Smart Filter with white.

---

This does *not* assist with distortion filters such as Spherize. You will need to separate pieces to apply the spherize filter to a specific area. You simply can't use those type of filters on *part* of a layer.

You can *mask* a protion of the filter, but the result isn't quite the same:

[image]

Much like CMYK/RGB and filters.. some things only work one way if the image itself meets requirements. Smart object are seen as a whole layer for smart filters.... you can only mask the filter, not restrict it to a specific area. Raster content is required if you wish to restrict a filter to a selection.